# Eliminating duplicate columns using query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, each of 100 columns which i need to join and the result should contain all the columns from both the tables except the primary key column which should appear only once in the beggining like the following :

```
table_1:

pid     sname     sschool     snumber.............col 100


table_2 :

pid     sregion  sdistrict    slanguage............col 100
```

I have written a simple inner join query :

```
  select a.* , b.*
  from table_1 inner join table_2
  on a.pid = b.pid ;
```

It results in joining both the tables  like the following

```
pid  sname sschool snumber...........pid sregion sdistrict slanguage
```

but i want to eliminate the duplicate b.pid column...instead i just want to keep one a.pid column in the beggining.

How can we eliminate that ?

P.S : I know its a bad db design and its better to normalize the data, but lack of time wont allow it.

Comment: Cannot see any reason why mongodb or couchdb tags were used. Getting the feeling that the mysql and sqlserver people are going to feel the same. Don't choose tags to "get attention". Instead only tag relevant to the actual thing your question is about. Doing otherwise just annoys people and makes it unclear which technology you are actually using or talking about.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: You need to select the pId only from one of the tables in the join, select `a.pId` and then list all other columns you need. Do you really have 100 columns on a table? You can write `select a.*, b.col2, b.col3, ....., b.col100` (to manually write only 100 cols of the second table)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to not use *'s in the SELECT list, or at the very least, to only use them on one of the tables being joined:

```
SELECT a.Col1, a.Col2, ... a.Coln, b.Col2, b.Col3, ... b.ColN
FROM ...
```

or

```
SELECT a.*, b.Col2, b.Col3, ... b.ColN
FROM ...
```